# What is the optimal method for interfacing a 12VDC or 24VDC relay using a 48VDC supply in an automotive application?

Tags: voltage, relay, buck, voltage-divider, automotive

I need to interface a 12VDC **or** 24VDC relay into a 48VDC (nominal voltage) battery pack for switching applications in my **automotive design.**

Directly driving the relay coil with the 48VDC battery pack is not feasible, so I'm exploring the best method to interface the relay.

There are two potential ways to achieve this:

Voltage divider circuit (using resistors).
Step-down SMPS (Switch-Mode Power Supply).
Please advise on the optimal method to interface the 12VDC or 24VDC relay into my application. Thank you.

Comment: Why not use a 48 V DC relay?

Comment: Few reasons. Many relay manufactures do not develop PCB type 48VDC.  Second one is cost.

Comment: Given that telephone installations are very frequently 48V, are you sure you can't find good PCB 48VDC relays?  A quick check found dozens under EUR 5 from Omron, TE, Axion, Panasonic with many contact choices up to about 16 A.  From a reliability standpoint, a designed-for-purpose relay is likely to be much better than something with a (possibly quite hot) adaptation.  What are the other requirements for the relay that makes you rule this out?

Comment: Actually, I am also taking vibrations into consideration. I'm not sure how the relays used for telephone applications respond to vibrations. We primarily use 24VDC relays, with only a few 48VDC relay requirements. If we could purchase all the relays from one type, it would save money. That was my main concern.

Comment: Could you post a part number or datasheet for a typical 24VDC relay that you'd like to use?

Comment: I think providing datasheet or part numbers does not help to solve my problem. Any how, I am still at planning stage .  https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/164/ftr_e1-1285186.pdf    . But I found this

Comment: Putting a resistor in series would work but you need to consider the inrush of the coil, shunt the resistor with a cap, that will give you a fast turn on. The cap will supply the additional current needed to close the gap when the contacts close. You get to determine the size as there is not enough information here to do that.

Comment: @Gil there is no inrush on a DC coil relay. A series resistor and 48V will result in faster pull-in than a ‘stiff’ 24V supply because motion depends on coil current.

Answer (score 1):

Using resistors, if there are good conditions for cooling

Comment: Yah, resistors can be used as voltage divider. But I am not sure whether this is an best practice for automotive application

Comment: @HANSDpmco, if you use wire wound resistors, Vasily's solution is, from the point of view of functional safety, possibly the best not only for automotive but even for railway applications. The failure mode of this components are simpler and better understood than the ones of any AEQ certified IC, and moreover their ambient operating temperature exceed the maximum one allowed for semiconductors.

Comment: Actually, I am seeking information about the standard practices used for this kind of application. Thank you very much, Daniele, for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Using a resistor in series with the coil is a simple and economical solution.

[image]

Standard automotive relays are available in a range of coil voltages (6, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60 and 72 V DC) and have a coil consumption of 1.8 W.

The 24 V coil has a resistance of 324 Ω.

A 324 Ω - 3 W voltage dropping resistor should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Drive the coil with a current not a voltage. There are families of semiconductors designed specifically for this application.

Comment: Did you mean relay economizer circuits right ? As I am aware of it,  they control the contactor using PWM signal. Am I correct?  If your suggestion is that, cost is the problem again!

Answer (score 0):

Sure the resistor is simple and easy when the power is low .Efficiency can be low when considering a 12VDC relay coil running of 48VDC via a resistor that drops 36VDC .25% is expected in this case .PWM would have losses of less than 10% and is not difficult to do these days.